# confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1 does not start on a remote docker service (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, testcontainers

Trying to run a container from "confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1" image on a remote docker server via testcontainers.

```
        KAFKA = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"))
                .withExposedPorts(9092, 9093);
        KAFKA.start();
```

On the local DockerDesktop (macOS) all works fine.
But on the remote server (Ubuntu 20.04)... I am getting error assigning port 9092 and container fails to start.
Have anyone faced same issues? How to fix it?

Here is the log:

```
10:24:24.757 [docker-java-stream--1208298425] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "/bin/bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/9092: Cannot assign requested address[\n]"
10:24:40.284 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000B: cancel
10:24:40.284 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: close connection IMMEDIATE
10:24:40.285 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000B: endpoint closed
10:24:40.285 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000000B: discarding endpoint
10:24:40.285 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000B: releasing endpoint
10:24:40.285 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000B: connection is not kept alive
10:24:40.285 [testcontainers-wait-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000000B: connection released [route: {}->http://7.134.137.18:2375][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2147483647; total allocated: 0 of 2147483647]
10:24:40.285 [docker-java-stream--1208298425] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: Socket closed"
00:04:37.361 [main] DEBUG  [confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1] - Wait strategy threw an exception
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (7.134.137.18 ports: [32769, 32770, 32771] should be listening)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:90)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:51)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:929)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:468)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:331)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:329)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:317)
    at com.qwerty.e2e.AbstractTest.<clinit>(AbstractTest.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:547)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:497)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:226)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: The error says it's looking for ports other than 9092 and 9093...

Comment: Really, I don't  know why does it try to take ports [32769, 32770, 32771]. Suppose this is an internal image setup... I guess I can't influence on it...

Comment: Well, you've not added any environment variables to the container, so `withExposedPorts` alone doesn't do what you want for connections to a remote server

Comment: I think your real error is `/dev/tcp/localhost/9092: Cannot assign requested address`... Perhaps something already has that port on that machine?

Comment: No, this is a small virtual server with  only VPN on it.... what additional params i have to pass to the container?

Comment: For example, `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` environment variable sets what ports are used for connecting to the broker from remote client https://confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/